# How to write the output of a python script which is a set of float to a text file?

Tags: python, output

I have a python script which prints the first 105 columns of a text file. All the values are float and I want to write the list into a text file. I tried the code below, but the text file is empty.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

data = pd.read_csv('E:\Python_trials\Trial_codes\Lab_trial.txt', delimiter = '\t')
df = data.ix[:,:110]
print(df)

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    sys.stdout.writelines(str(f))
    f.flush()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont write to `f`. You are writing to standard output. Try `f.write(...)`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

data = pd.read_csv('E:\Python_trials\Trial_codes\Lab_trial.txt', delimiter = '\t')
df = data.ix[:,:110]
print(df)

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(f))
    # f.close() This is useless, as soon as the "with" is over, it automatically closes the file
```

Comment: Thank You for the response.

Comment: But, I am getting the below text in the file, test. txt  :                   <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>                   What I want to write is a set of rows and columns [252 rows x 105 columns]. Please help me out

Comment: You are currently write `f` to the file. `f` is a file handler, thanks why you see that. If you want to write "flower" for example, use `f.write("flower")`